# Time complexity when halving loop counter twice

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I know the time complexity when we halve loop counter is `log n`. That is, if we have following loop:

```
for(i=1 ; i<n ; i*=2) { ... }
```

then the time complexity turns out to be `log n`.

Shouldnt halving loop counter `i` again give `log log n` time complexity? That is for below loop

```
for(i=1 ; i<n ; i*=4) { ... }
```

is the time complexity `log log n`?

I tried some values for `n`:

```
n = 2^8 = 256
i = 1,4,16,64,256 (5 times)

n = 2^10 = 1024
i = 1,4,16,64,256,1024 (6 times)

n = 2^16 = 65536
i = 1,4,16,64,256,1024,4096,16384,65536 (9 times)
```

it seems that the loop body gets executed for `(log n)/2-1` times.
Am I correct with this analysis and halving loop counter twice does indeed still gives `O(log n)` time complexity and not `O(log log n)` time complexity?

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting the base. In the first case, we assume the base is 2, so we just write the complexity as `O(logn)`.

In the second case, the base should be 4 because the we are multiplying by 4 so it should be **O(log<sub>4</sub>n)**.

Comment: I came to know that if I do `i=i^2` I will get `O(log log n)` time complexity. Doing `i*=k`, gives `O(log_k(n))`. Does doing `i=i^k` has any parallel? Like for example `i=i^4` is `O(log log log log n)`

Comment: @anir, you should not extend your original question in comments. If you have a new question, ask a new question in the proper way. And in the mean time decide which answer to mark as accepted here.

Comment: Note that `O(log_4(n)) = O(0.5 * log_2(n)) = O(log_2(n))`. The base doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Right, this is why we say `O(log n)`, not just `log n`. BTW for actual log n you have to loop with `*e` or something like that

If you loop with `*4` it will be just two times faster and still `O(log n)`

In order to get O(log log n) you have to change your increase each time:

```
i*=2
i*=4 (= 2*2)
i*=16 (= 4*4)
i*=256 (= 16*16)
etc
```

Comment: **Q1.** What is the intuition behind changing the increase?

Comment: **Q2.** I came to know that if I do `i=i^2` I will get `O(log log n)` time complexity. How changing increase compares with this?

Comment: For **Q1** - on each step `m` the power will be `a^(a^m)` (in my case `2^(2^m)`) so m will be `O(log log i)`. For **Q2** - you are right, this is very similar, power will be , 1, 2, 4, 16, 256, etc so log will be 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, etc, therefore log log will be 1,2,3,4,... i.e. number of iterations.

Comment: @anir, you should not extend your original question in comments. If you have a new question, ask a new question in the proper way. And in the mean time decide which answer to mark as accepted here.

Comment: @trincot I know it may not be great to extend question. But these are related questions. If I have to ask new question, I have to re-establish the context of this question as I am asking how other form of iteration compare with this. Also attacking same concept from different direction by asking multiple related questions helps to grasp the concept clearly.

Comment: You should ask a new question. It is easy to establish the context. Comments are not intended for follow-up questions.

Comment: asked new extension question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59590182/generalizing-olog-log-n-time-complexity). Please see if am correct with generalizing O(log log n) complexity.